# iOS does not request AASA file on one device but works on all others

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

My app is configured for Universal Links. I've confirmed my setup works on multiple devices and simulators. However, I have an iPhone Xs Max running 13.3 where Universal Links does not work.

I've narrowed it down to the `swcd` process in iOS. This will normally fetch the AASA file when the app is installed. I can see this event succeed in the console for devices where Universal Links is working.

```
default 14:05:50.962587-0500    swcd    Completing request for 'https://www.mydomainn.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association', status 0/0x0 noErr
default 14:05:50.962776-0500    swcd    Updated app ID 'XXXXXXXX.com.my.app', domain 'www.mydomain.com', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x2 < SiteApproved > on check
```

But on this particular iPhone there is no `swcd` activity at all during app installation. It never checks for the file and Universal Links is not configured.

I've tested installing via Xcode and TestFlight with the same results. I've deleted the app, restarted, and re-installed multiple times. I did reset this device once which DID work, but after multiple subsequent re-installations of the app it stopped working again.

I believe I have it configured correctly since it works on all other devices and simulators I have tested. I need to get it working on this one too.

What could be preventing `swcd` from requesting the AASA file only on this device? Are there any further troubleshooting steps I can take?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181728/universal-links-deep-linking-not-working-on-iphone-but-works-on-ipad is it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running into one of these two bugs:

https://openradar.appspot.com/45201697

https://openradar.appspot.com/33893852

Delete the app, reboot the device, wait an hour or so then reinstall the app. That seems to force it to re-check the AASA.

Seems like there could be a process running after reboot blocking `swcd` from running.

Answer (score 4):

After debugging all day, i've came across on this topic and decided to reboot my device. After the reboot - the universal links and passwords started to work like a magic.